# foreach loop exceeds memory limit php

Tags: php, pdf, while-loop

```
<?php
require('fpdf.php');
$pdf = new FPDF();

$i=1;

while ($i<=$_GET['count']){
    $pdf->AddPage();
    $pdf->Image('http://image.example.com/'.$_GET['id'].'/jpg/page_'.$i.'.jpg',1,1,208,0);
    $i++;
}
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

when i try to convert 200 or more images with this code, it gives me "exceeded memory limit " eror. i tried to set memory limit higher but that does not work as i want .is it in my code and is there any other ways to prevent this error

**is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500**

Comment: Please ALWAY show us the complete error message and not a summary of it

Comment: put this "ini_set('display_errors', 1);" after "<?php" and write the error that signals you. 
should report the error in a specific way, in addition to responding with error 500 should put in the content of the page also indicated the queue and where it makes the error.

Comment: let us know what it says

Comment: i put the ini_set('display_errors', 1); code and the same, it shows only that error .

Comment: what about flush() can this help me somehow

Comment: @konakzizu, add exit before $pdf->Output(). try again